# Where do I put my custom .iss file when building a native JavaFX app with Intellij and Inno Setup?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, inno-setup, javafx-packager

I am using the artifact build feature of IntelliJ IDEA but the build always seems to use the default package resource and tells me to `add package/windows/AppName.iss to the class path to customise`. I have tried couple of locations but my custom script still does not get picked up by the JavaFX Packager during the artifact build. Here is a snippet of the build output

```
Java FX Packager: No base JDK. Package will use system JRE.
Java FX Packager: Running [C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\bin\java, -version]
Java FX Packager: Running [C:\Program Files (x86)\Inno Setup 5\iscc.exe, /?]
Java FX Packager:   Detected [C:\Program Files (x86)\Inno Setup 5\iscc.exe] version [5]
Java FX Packager:   Using default package resource [application icon]  (add package/windows/ControlExp1.ico to the class path to customize)
Java FX Packager: Running [C:\Users\ysparrow\AppData\Local\Temp\iconswap2091256136799880247.exe, C:\Users\ysparrow\AppData\Local\Temp\fxbundler511500059683716516\windows\ControlExp1.ico, C:\Users\ysparrow\AppData\Local\Temp\fxbundler511500059683716516\images\win-exe.image\ControlExp1\ControlExp1.exe]
Java FX Packager: Icon File Name: C:\Users\ysparrow\AppData\Local\Temp\fxbundler511500059683716516\windows\ControlExp1.ico
Java FX Packager: Executable File Name: C:\Users\ysparrow\AppData\Local\Temp\fxbundler511500059683716516\images\win-exe.image\ControlExp1\ControlExp1.exe
Java FX Packager:   Config files are saved to C:\Users\ysparrow\AppData\Local\Temp\fxbundler511500059683716516\windows. Use them to customize package.
Java FX Packager:   Using default package resource [Inno Setup project file]  (add package/windows/ControlExp1.iss to the class path to customize)
Java FX Packager:   Using default package resource [setup dialog icon]  (add package/windows/ControlExp1-setup-icon.bmp to the class path to customize)
Java FX Packager: Using default package resource [script to run after application image is populated]  (add package/windows/ControlExp1-post-image.wsf to the class path to customize)
Java FX Packager: Generating EXE for installer to: C:\Users\ysparrow\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IdeaIC2021.1\compile-server\controlexperiment1_ff845e1b\_temp_\artifactunzipped\deploy\bundles
Java FX Packager: Running [C:\Program Files (x86)\Inno Setup 5\iscc.exe, /oC:\Users\ysparrow\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IdeaIC2021.1\compile-server\controlexperiment1_ff845e1b\_temp_\artifactunzipped\deploy\bundles, C:\Users\ysparrow\AppData\Local\Temp\fxbundler511500059683716516\images\win-exe.image\ControlExp1.iss] in C:\Users\ysparrow\AppData\Local\Temp\fxbundler511500059683716516\images\win-exe.image
```

I want to know the right place to put the `package/windows/AppName.iss` in the IntelliJ project directory. Thank you in advance.